# Error in starting IBM AMQP service in IBM 8.0.0.5

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, amqp, jms-topic

We are trying to create Java MQ light publisher and subscriber to IBM MQ 8.0.0.5 AMQP topic

We run the script `/opt/mqm/amqp/samples/SampleMQM.sh` to create Queue Manager, Start AMQP service, Start a channel on port 5672[Java MQ Light Git Repository](https://github.com/mqlight/java-mqlight)

We are getting error starting default AMQP service `SYSTEM.AMQP.SERVICE`

> ```
> 9/23/20 10:19:04.511  AMQXR0005I: Running
> com.ibm.mq.MQXRService.RunMQXRService version null.
>
> AMQCO2005I: Formatter stopped at:10:19:04 AM GMT Wednesday, September
> 23, 2020
>
> AMQCO2004I: Formatter started at:10:19:04 AM GMT Wednesday, September
> 23, 2020
>
> 9/23/20 10:19:04.523  AMQUT0007I: The java.util.logging configuration
> is now set to
> /var/mqm/qmgrs/AMQP_SAMPLE_QM/./amqp/amqptraceOff.properties.
>
> 9/23/20 10:19:07.227  AMQCO2001E: An error (probe: XR063017) occurred
> and a Failure Data Capture (FDC) file has been written to file
> '/var/mqm/errors/AMQP5.FDC'.
>
> 9/23/20 10:19:07.229  AMQXR0008E: Exception during start up of MQXR
> service: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> com/ibm/mq/headers/pcf/PCFMessageAgent
> ```

```
com.ibm.mq.headers.jar

com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar

com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar
```

are present in classpath

Additional errors are

> ```
> 09/23/20 13:15:14 - Process(5142.1) User(root) Program(amqzmgr0)
>                     Host(ccxluf02) Installation(Installation1)
>                     VRMF(8.0.0.5) QMgr(AMQP_SAMPLE_QM)
>
> AMQ5028: The Server 'SYSTEM.AMQP.SERVICE' has started.
> ProcessId(24163).
>
> EXPLANATION: The Server process has started. ACTION: None.
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
> 09/23/20 13:15:16 - Process(24190.1) User(mqm) Program(java)
>                     Host(ccxluf02) Installation(Installation1)
>                     VRMF(8.0.0.5) QMgr(AMQP_SAMPLE_QM)
>
> AMQ6175: The system could not dynamically load the shared library
> '/opt/mqm/lib64/amqzfud'. The system returned error message 'ld.so.1:
> java: fatal: relocation error: file /opt/mqm/lib64/amqzfud: symbol
> CSCtrl: referenced symbol not found'.
>
> EXPLANATION: This message applies to UNIX systems. The shared library
> '/opt/mqm/lib64/amqzfud' failed to load correctly due to a problem
> with the library. ACTION: Check the file access permissions and that
> the file has not been corrupted.
> ----- amqxufnx.c : 1436 ------------------------------------------------------- 
> 09/23/20 13:15:18 - Process(5142.1) User(root) Program(amqzmgr0)
>                     Host(ccxluf02) Installation(Installation1)
>                     VRMF(8.0.0.5) QMgr(AMQP_SAMPLE_QM)
>
> AMQ5029: The Server 'SYSTEM.AMQP.SERVICE' has ended. ProcessId(24163).
>
> EXPLANATION: The Server process has ended. ACTION: None.
> ```

Comment: With all due respect, this seems to be a question about MQ administration, not programming. It also seems to be the kind of issue you should be asking IBM to help with ;) Sorry if I'm missing the point.

Comment: Are you using the version of AMQP service that came with your 8.0.0.5 queue manager or is there some reason you have put a link to the MQ Light Git Hub repository near the beginning of your question? The error shows a failure to load amqzfud, which according to some search hits appears to be related to the LDAP support in MQ, which was added on the Windows platform later than V8, can't remember for UNIX exactly which version. Any chance you could try this with a version of IBM MQ which is actually in support? Like V9.2 for example?

Comment: Could resolve the earlier issue because jars mentioned in the question were older and replaced them with newer jars.

Comment: @MoragHughson ... in amqp .. we have created a durable subscriber for our topic but it is not getting if it is stopped .. msgs are sent to topic and restarted again .... We have called session.createDurableSubscriber(ourTopic, "<subscriberName>"); from our code where session is Javax.jms.session object... ?

Comment: I also suggest you self answer this question as it seems you found the problem, but it is not clear what the problem was exactly.